# How to write a Dockerfile for an AWS Lambda function deployed as a container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rust, aws-lambda

I've been writing an application on AWS that consists of several Rust lambdas. One of those lambdas has to have access to a bunch of external dependencies and therefore needs to be Dockerized. As I understand, the official AWS Lambda runtime for Rust runs within the lambda's binary and shouldn't need any special setup or exposing of ports.
My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
# building omitted
FROM alpine:latest AS runner
WORKDIR /root/
COPY target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/my-lambda ./my-lambda
CMD [ "/root/my-lambda" ]
```

The image then gets built and pushed to an Amazon ECR registry my Lambda is configured to get its code from.
The logs I get when invoking the function with any test data in the AWS console are:

```
IMAGE   Launch error: fork/exec /root/my-lambda: permission denied  Entrypoint: []  Cmd: [/root/my-lambda]  WorkingDir: [/root/]
START RequestId:  (...) Version: $LATEST
IMAGE   Launch error: fork/exec /root/my-lambda: permission denied  Entrypoint: []  Cmd: [/root/my-lambda]  WorkingDir: [/root/]
END RequestId:  (...)
REPORT RequestId:  (...)    Duration: 59.75 ms  Billed Duration: 60 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 5 MB   
RequestId: (...) Error: fork/exec /root/my-lambda: permission denied
Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: (...) Error: fork/exec /root/my-lambda: permission denied",
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint"
}
```

I know the problem is not with:

- the `my-lambda` executable file's permissions (anyone can execute it, I've tried chmod -R 777 for good measure too)
- the availability of libc (I specifically compiled for the musl target, as is best practice for Rust lambdas due to the Rust stdlib almost always linking to a newer glibc than Amazon Linux has)
- whether or not the Docker image even runs - if I try to run the image locally, my lambda runs and crashes on not finding the AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API env var or other variables lambdas depend on, as expected
- the executable's naming or if it's invoked with a relative path - naming it `bootstrap` in line with lambda convention and finishing with `CMD ["./bootstrap"]` did not help

I've also tried using an `ENTRYPOINT` rather than a `CMD` in the dockerfile, as well as providing a placeholder `CMD` like `doesnt.matter`.

Googling around for a solution has only turned up Rust lambda builder images and similar-looking but unrelated errors for Golang.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, figured it out:

```
FROM alpine:latest AS runner
WORKDIR /var/task/
COPY target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/my-lambda /var/task/my-lambda
CMD [ "./bootstrap" ]
```

Turns out that the executable must be in the /var/task/ directory.

Comment: Note that AWS is providing a useful environment variable to avoid hardcoding /var/task, you could use LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html