# What should be run in a container for a PHP-based Docker AWS lambda?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

PHP isn't a natively supported language in AWS Lambda, but I thought I'd try my hand at getting one working, using a custom Docker image. I am using [this official AWS example](https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/blob/master/0.7-PHP-Lambda-functions-with-Docker-container-images/Dockerfile) to structure the image.

I don't quite understand the pieces yet. I will add what files I have to this post.

Firstly, my Dockerfile:

```
# Demo of a PHP-based lambda
#
# See example:
# https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/blob/master/0.7-PHP-Lambda-functions-with-Docker-container-images/Dockerfile

FROM php:8.0-cli-alpine

WORKDIR /root

# Install Composer
COPY bin bin
RUN sh /root/bin/install-composer.sh
RUN php /root/composer.phar --version

# Install Composer deps
COPY composer.json composer.lock /root/
RUN php composer.phar install

# Install runtimes
COPY runtime /var/runtime
COPY src /var/task/

# Entrypoint
CMD ["index"]
```

Based on the example I also have:

- A PHP listener program at `/var/runtime/bootstrap` (nearly verbatim copy of the example repo)
- Composer dependencies at `/root/vendor/...` that are loaded by the bootstrap
- A trivial index file at `/var/task/index.php` (verbatim copy of the example repo)

One change I have made is to base the image on an Alpine image from PHP, rather than to use an Amazon Linux image. I wonder, could there be something in the Amazon image that is needed?

The test I am using is the "hello world" in the AWS Lambda UI:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

Anyway, I have used `docker login` and `docker push` to get the image to ECR. When I run the hello world test inside the AWS dashboard, I am getting this set of error logs in CloudWatch:

```
2021-11-13T19:12:12.449+00:00   IMAGE Launch error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: permission denied Entrypoint: [docker-php-entrypoint] Cmd: [index] WorkingDir: [/root]
2021-11-13T19:12:12.493+00:00   START RequestId: 38da1e10-4c93-4109-be10-32c58f83a2fb Version: $LATEST
2021-11-13T19:12:12.502+00:00   IMAGE Launch error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: permission denied Entrypoint: [docker-php-entrypoint] Cmd: [index] WorkingDir: [/root]
2021-11-13T19:12:12.504+00:00   END RequestId: 38da1e10-4c93-4109-be10-32c58f83a2fb
2021-11-13T19:12:12.504+00:00   REPORT RequestId: 38da1e10-4c93-4109-be10-32c58f83a2fb Duration: 9.20 ms Billed Duration: 10 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 3 MB
2021-11-13T19:12:12.504+00:00   RequestId: 38da1e10-4c93-4109-be10-32c58f83a2fb Error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: permission denied Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

That makes a lot of sense, as I don't understand the entry point of "index" either, but it's there as a `CMD` in the example Dockerfile. Is this an alias for something? I would be inclined to use something like `php /var/runtime/bootstrap`, but I'd rather understand things, rather than guessing.

I believe I might be able to use [Lambda RIE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html) to test this locally, but I wonder if that would tell me what I already know - I need to fix the `CMD`.

For what it's worth, I can't see how the `index.php` file is triggered in the lambda either. How does that get invoked?

### Update

I am wondering if the parent image in the example (`public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided`) has an `ENTRYPOINT` that would shed some light on the apparently confusing `CMD`. I wonder if I will investigate that next.

### Update 2

The ponderance that I might have to use the Amazon Linux image parent was a false steer - [this official resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) shows the use of standard Python and Node images.

I decided to try repairing the main Docker command:

```
CMD ["php", "/var/runtime/bootstrap"]
```

However it doesn't like that:

```
START RequestId: d95a29d3-6764-4bae-9976-09830c1c17af Version: $LATEST
IMAGE   Launch error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: permission denied Entrypoint: [docker-php-entrypoint] Cmd: [php,/var/runtime/bootstrap]   WorkingDir: [/root]
IMAGE   Launch error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: permission denied Entrypoint: [docker-php-entrypoint] Cmd: [php,/var/runtime/bootstrap]   WorkingDir: [/root]
END RequestId: d95a29d3-6764-4bae-9976-09830c1c17af
REPORT RequestId: d95a29d3-6764-4bae-9976-09830c1c17af  Duration: 19.88 ms  Billed Duration: 20 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 3 MB   
RequestId: d95a29d3-6764-4bae-9976-09830c1c17af Error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: permission denied
Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

### Update 3

No matter what I do, I seem to run into problems with entrypoints. I've even tried a runtime script to `chmod +x` on the various binaries it doesn't like, but of course if I try to kick that off in the `ENTRYPOINT`, the container believes that `/bin/sh` cannot be executed. This is getting rather silly - containers are just not behaving correctly in the Lambda environment.

### Update 4

I have now tried to move away from Alpine, in case a more standard OS will work correctly. No joy - I get the same. I'm now at the random-trying things point, and this is rather slow going, given that the build-push-install loop is cumbersome.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517082/how-to-write-a-dockerfile-for-an-aws-lambda-function-deployed-as-a-container) looks promising, but putting the bootstrap file in `/var/task` seems to go directly against the example I am working from.

Comment: I wonder if I should try the example with AWS Linux absolutely verbatim - given my bumpy experience so far I wonder if I am making a systemic error that I can't see, and that "just trying new things" is a waste of time until I can see what the major issue is.

Comment: All the failure messages above relate to file permissions by the looks of it (by file permissions i mean perms on both the files themselves, AND all parent folders in path to files) - i think using /root/ is your issue. One of the pages you link explicitly states - `Install any dependencies under the ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT} directory alongside the function handler to ensure that the Lambda runtime can locate them when the function is invoked.` and they mention `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task`

Comment: Alright, thanks @MisterSmith - good find on the docs. It seems to go against the example, but I think I did get a somewhat different error by moving my bootstrap file from `/var/runtime` to `/var/task`. The official example doesn't seem to do this though, and moreover PHP libs are put in `/opt/vendor`.

Comment: Thanks again @MisterSmith - solution stumbled upon, answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was tricksy because there were two major interlocking problems - a seemingly excessive permissions requirement, and what struck me as a non-standard use of the ENTRYPOINT/CMD systems.

### Working solution

The Dockerfile that works is as follows:

```
# Demo of a PHP-based lambda
#
# See example:
# https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/blob/master/0.7-PHP-Lambda-functions-with-Docker-container-images/Dockerfile

FROM php:8.0-cli-alpine

WORKDIR /root

# Install Composer
COPY bin bin
RUN sh /root/bin/install-composer.sh
RUN php /root/composer.phar --version

# Install Composer deps
COPY composer.json composer.lock /root/
# Move deps to /opt, /root has significant permission issues
RUN php /root/composer.phar install && \
    mv /root/vendor /opt/vendor

# Install runtimes
COPY runtime/bootstrap /var/runtime/
COPY src/index.php /var/task/

RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/php /var/task/* /var/runtime/*

# The entrypoint seems to be the main handler
# and the CMD specifies what kind of event to process
WORKDIR /var/task
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/runtime/bootstrap"]
CMD ["index"]
```

So, that resolves one of my nagging questions about Amazon Linux - it is not required. Note that although I installed Composer dependencies in `/root`, they could not stay there - even `777` perms on them seemed to be insufficient.

As you can see I used 777 permissions on things in `/var`. 755 might work, maybe even 750 would work - but the key here is that Amazon appears to be a user that is not the build (root) user. That tripped me up a lot.

Now the `ENTRYPOINT` is used to run the bootstrap script, which appears to be doing general mediation between events on the AWS side and "use cases" in `/var/tasks`. The normal purpose of a Docker entrypoint is as a command wrapper to `CMD`, so to use `CMD` as a "default lambda type" seems to significantly violate the principle of least surprise. I would have thought the lambda type would be defined by the incoming event, not by any lambda-side setting.

### Testing

To test this lambda I use this event in the Lambda UI:

```
{
  "queryStringParameters": { "name": "halfer" }
}
```

And the demo code will respond with:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST"
  },
  "body": "Hello, halfer"
}
```

Suffice it to say this feels rather brittle. Admittedly the demo code is not production quality, but even so, I suspect this would need a pipeline to do a real AWS Lambda test prior to merging down or deployment.

### Performance

Here is why lambdas are tempting, especially for infrequent calls such as crons - they are instantiated quickly and die quickly, leaving no running infra. In one of my demo calls I have:

```
Init duration     188.75 ms
Duration           39.45 ms
Billed duration   229 ms
```

### Deeper understanding

Having worked with the pieces I think I can now explain them rather better, and what I thought of as unusual architectural choices may actually have some purpose. I fear however this design ideology is not sufficiently documented, so engineers working with Docker-based AWS Lambdas have to spend additional time figuring the pieces out.

Consider the processing loop in the [demo runtime](https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/blob/master/0.7-PHP-Lambda-functions-with-Docker-container-images/runtime/bootstrap):

```
// This is the request processing loop. Barring unrecoverable failure, this loop runs until the environment shuts down.
do {
    // Ask the runtime API for a request to handle.
    $request = getNextRequest();

    // Obtain the function name from the _HANDLER environment variable and ensure the function's code is available.
    $handlerFunction = $_ENV['_HANDLER'];
    require_once $_ENV['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] . '/' . $handlerFunction . '.php';

    // Execute the desired function and obtain the response.
    $response = $handlerFunction($request['payload']);

    // Submit the response back to the runtime API.
    sendResponse($request['invocationId'], $response);
} while (true);
```

This picks up `$_ENV['_HANDLER']` from the Lambda environment, and AWS derives that from the `CMD` of the image. Now, in PHP the env vars in `$_ENV` are static for the duration of the process, so it is perhaps a slightly odd choice to read this in a loop and include the file in a loop - it would have been better to do this in an initialisation phase, returning a clean error if the include isn't found.

However, here's the likely purpose of this system: AWS Lambdas let users customise the `CMD` in the web dashboard. So in an example enterprise let's say that there's three lambdas - one for responding to a web event, one for a scheduler, and one for responding to SNS topics. The handlers for each of these could be added to the same image, allowing the three lambdas to share an image - all they need to do is to supply a `CMD` override, and each one will load and use the right handler.